# how to switch the version of ocaml compiler in a docker container without --privilege

Tags: linux, docker, ocaml

Now the version of OCaml compiler in my ubuntu20.04 docker container is 4.08.1, however I need OCaml 3.12.1 to build a project. So I tried `opam switch create 3.12.1` and get an error like this:

> The compilation of ocaml-base-compiler failed at "/root/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build
> ./configure -prefix /root/.opam/3.12.1".

> ...

> bwrap: Creating new namespace failed: Operation not permitted

the docker container is running without --privilege option, I guess this may be the reason. However, I have been using this container for a long time, so it may be diffcult to commit it or migrate its content to another container. Is there any other approach to use a specific-version OCaml compiler?

Comment: A Docker container runs a copy of an image, which in turn is an immutable copy of an application and its runtime dependencies.  You'd almost never change software versions (and especially major versions of the language runtime) inside a running container; install the right version in your image's Dockerfile instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable sandboxing when initializing opam with

```
opam init --disable-sandboxing
```

With this configuration option, `opam` will not call `bubblewrap` when building package thus avoiding the issue with nested sandboxing.